# Function return value can't be assigned to a const char value

Tags: c

I am using OpenGL, don't worry my problem is with C and not something related to OpenGL. In OpenGL, we have something called shaders. It is a text file. All I want to do is to read that text file and pass it to a function that accepts only `const char * const*`. (eg. `func(&shaderSource)` and `shaderSource` must be `const char* shaderSource`.). I just want this terminology with multiple files. Can I? I saw people doing this with C++, but I chose C over C++ in the project. Here is some of my failed attempts.

```
char vertexShaderContent[1000] = readfile("Shader/default.frag.txt");
const char *vertexShaderSource;
strcpy(vertexShaderSource, vertexShaderContent);
```

Here I tried to get a new variable (By the way this is in the `main` function) that executes the function and gets the return value of that function. Now I did copy that string (using `strcat`) to assign the value of `vertexShaderContent` to `vertexShaderSource`. By the way here is my `readfile` code:

```
char *readfile(const char* filename) {
    char *res = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 100);    
    char *word = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(word, sizeof(word), file) != NULL) {
        strcat(res, word);
    }

    strcat(res, "\n\0");

    fclose(file);

    return res;
}
```

**Summary**

All my problem is that I want to pass a `char*` to a function accepting `const char*`s. If I can't, is there is any way I can get this 'multiple' files to work?

Thanks.

Comment: `const char *vertexShaderSource = readfile(...);`?

Comment: Code is text, so don't post it as images

Comment: And there's a lot of other errors in your code, starting with wrong allocation sizes (`sizeof(char*)` instead of `sizeof(char)`), undefined behavior with calling `strcat` on an uninitialized buffer and trying to `strcpy` into an uninitialized pointer

Comment: Pass a pointer to vertexShaderContent to readFile instead of using malloc.

Comment: @UnholySheep This does not get an error and it works fine. I know it is not best practice. Perhaps I can fix it later. Also I won't post as images again

Comment: Do not post text as images. As long as there is no source code in text in your question, it is unsuitable for Stack Overflow, will be voted down, and likely will be closed.

Comment: The mods are too strict. I can't believe it. The idea to post images instead of text sounded cool to me

Comment: Read the information about posting a [mre]. Narrow your post down to one specific question and one specific piece of code. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site; you should learn C by reading and working through a primer or textbook or taking a class. You say “All my problem is that I want to pass a `char*` to a function accepting `const char*`, but that is allowed by C; it should not generate an error. So you need to show a specific piece of code with that error, including a complete source file other people can compile to reproduce the error, and the compiler error message it produced.

Comment: I did search before I post. And I found nothing. Or at least nothing was the same issue I searched for. And I got many errors in the process. But my main problem is passing a fnction to function allowing const chars* can I?

Comment: @EricPostpischi I am not asking for the exact source code of something. I am just asking for how to pass a function that returns `char *` to a `const char*`. That's it. Don't over exaggerate too much. I just want an answer. Or if I made a mistake trying to ask a question. What should I do then?

Comment: @TechTycho: I did not say you are asking for exact code. I said **you** should provide source code. That is a Stack Overflow guideline for debugging questions: The asker should provide source code that other people can compile to reproduce the problem. It provides clarity and ease. Since you have not done that (as well as other reasons), your question is being voted down and will likely be closed. Read the information about providing a [mre].

Comment: Fixed it @EricPostpischil., Now please give me an answer to my question

Answer (score 3):

In `char vertexShaderContent[1000] = readfile("Shader/default.frag.txt");`, `readfile` returns a pointer to `char`, but `vertexShaderContent` is an array of `char`. To initialize an array, one needs to provide values for each element to be initialized. A pointer to `char` is not a correct type for initializing `char` values.

What may work here is `char *vertexShaderContent = readfile("Shader/default.frag.txt");`. That defines `vertexShaderContent` to be a pointer to the memory returned by `readfile`. However, it is not clear what you want to do, because the code that follows it is confusing:

```
const char *vertexShaderSource;
strcpy(vertexShaderContent, vertexShaderSource);
```

This would overwrite the data at `vertexShaderContent` with new data, so it loses the data that `readfile` returned. And it attempts to copy from `vertexShaderSource`, but `vertexShaderSource` has not been set to point to anywhere. Its value is indeterminate. This `strcpy` cannot do anything useful. Since we do not know what you are trying to do here, we cannot recommend a solution.

These lines in `readfile` are incorrect:

```
char *res = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 100);
char *word = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

The first allocates space for 100 `char *`. To allocate space for 100 `char`, use `char *res = malloc(100 * sizeof *res);`.

The second allocates space for one `char *`. But it looks like you want space for one “word”, which would likely be some varying number of characters. Maybe you would want to start with space for at least 100 characters:

```
char *word = malloc(100 * sizeof *word);
```

That could help get the code going at first, although a good eventual solution would ensure the allocated spacer could not be overflowed.

In `strcat(res, word)`, the data pointed to by `res` has not yet been initialized. Before using `strcat`, you must have some string in the destination. That can be the empty string, which you can create by putting a null terminator character in `res`:

```
*res = '\0';
```

> All my problem is that I want to pass a `char*` to a function accepting `const char*`s.

Nothing in the question shows any attempt to pass a `char *` for a `const char *` parameter that would not work, except for the issues noted above.

Comment: Sorry. In `strcpy`. I meant `strcpy(vertexShaderSource, vertexShaderContent)` I 'll fix it

Comment: Yeah can you show me a way to parse a `char *` to `const char *` just for me to pass the `vertexShaderSource` to the function that needs a `const char * const *`. (not the `readFile`) function.

Comment: @TechTycho: To call a function that requires a `const char * const *` using a `char *x;`, use `& (const char *) {x}` as the argument. That creates a temporary `const char *` that points to the same place as `x` and passes its address to the function.

Comment: Thanks Eric! very cool